# Sharepoint services

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a Word document 2013 VisualStudio solution, and I tried to add a web reference "_**vti_bin / Lists.asmx**", but it shows me an error message "Error downloading" **http: // [web path]:80** / _ vti_bin / ListData.svc request error with the following **HTTP 404 steps: Not Found**". .
On the other hand, when I write my Central Administration address, it works well. But the services are executed on the site of the Central Administrator.

I'm use Sharepoint 2010 and I tried that, becouse i need attach my word document to an item adding by my code. Please apologize my english. And thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the endpoint below to access search.asmx web service:

```
http://Server_Name/[sites/][Site_Name/]_vti_bin/search.asmx
```

And here is a demo about use search.asmx in SharePoint 2013:

[Walkthrough: Querying SharePoint Search From a Client Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff394650(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not what I need

Comment: http : //Server_Name/[sites/][Site_Name/]_vti_bin/search.asmx is the same as http: // [web path]:80 / _ vti_bin / Lists.svc request. them this does not solve anything

Comment: @Batista have you tried it without the `:80` port number?

Comment: I tried with my Administration Center port, and work, but not with my app port